# Windows feature pack not installed, installer saying it is

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-media-player

When trying to install windows feature pack the installer says that it is already installed on my Windows 10 pro N machine, but programs that require it (GTA 5) are saying that it is missing. The installer in question is "Windows10-KB3010081-x64". Is there anyway to force the installer to run regardless of the content apparently being on my machine, or is there a way to manually install the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had the wrong version of windows feature pack, the correct version was "KB3099229_x64.msu", found at "https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/E/3/BE302763-5BFD-4209-9C98-02DF5B2DB452/KB3099229_x64.msu"